# Execute query and grab result in two subsections mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongoose to deal with my database.

I have the following model:

```
var DeviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    type: Number,
    pushId: String
});
```

The type attribute can be either 0 or 1.

I want to execute a query that grab all documents and retrieve the result in the following format:

```
{
    fstType: [
        {
             _id: "545d533e2c21b900000ad234",
             type: 0,
             pushId: "123"
        },
        {
             _id: "545d533e2c21b900000ad235",
             type: 0,
             pushId: "124"
        },
    ],
    sndType: [
        {
             _id: "545d533e2c21b900000ad236",
             type: 1,
             pushId: "125"
        },
        {
             _id: "545d533e2c21b900000ad237",
             type: 1,
             pushId: "126"
        },
    ]
}
```

Is that possible? I want to do that in one single query.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a sample document of `user` and `device`, and the sample output?

Comment: Great, Let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is that possible? I want to do that in one single query.*

Yes. It is possible. You can achieve the desired result, through the following `aggregation` pipeline operations.

- `Sort` by the `type` parameter in ascending order.
- `Group` records together having the same `type`, construct an array of
  documents for each group. After this stage, only two records will be
  present, each with an attribute called `items`, which is an array of
  records for each group.
- Since our records are sorted by `type`, the `first` group will contain
  records with type `0`, and the `second` with type `1`.

At last we merge the groups and give them each a name, based on their `type`.

```
var model = mongoose.model('collection',DeviceSchema);

model.aggregate([
{$sort:{"type":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$type",
         "items":{$push:"$$ROOT"},
         "type":{$first:"$type"}}},
{$project:{"items":{$cond:[{$eq:["$type",0]},
                           {"firstType":"$items"},
                           {"secondType":"$items"}]}}},
{$group:{"_id":null,
         "firstType":{$first:"$items.firstType"},
         "secondType":{$last:"$items.secondType"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"firstType":1,"secondType":1}}
], function (err, result) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
return;
}
console.log(result);
});
```

**o/p:**

```
{ firstType: 
   [ { _id: '545d533e2c21b900000ad234', type: 0, pushId: '123' },
     { _id: '545d533e2c21b900000ad235', type: 0, pushId: '124' } ],
  secondType: 
   [ { _id: '545d533e2c21b900000ad236', type: 1, pushId: '125' },
     { _id: '545d533e2c21b900000ad237', type: 1, pushId: '126' } ] }
```